# Struts2: How do I tell my index.jsp to forward to a struts2 action?

Tags: java, web-applications, frameworks, struts2

Oftentimes when I see an index.jsp on a web application it just forwards to another url like login.jsp such as

```
<jsp:forward page="login.jsp" />
```

When using struts2, I want a similar index.jsp but I want it to forward to an action. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use plain HTML if you want

Between your head tags use:

```
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=Login.action">
```

This will redirect to myCOntext/Login.action

If Login is behind a name space you wil need to include that in the URL

Comment: Thank you alzoid. Never thought it would be that simple :)

Comment: Probably irrelevant for this case, but this is redirect, NOT forward.

Answer (score 3):

Scriplet:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%  
response.sendRedirect("/Project/namespace/Login.action");
%>
```

I use it with Struts2 and it works.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but I'm trying to avoid using scriptlets ;)

Comment: @Trick in struts2 scriplets should be avoid.

Comment: True. I do this now, but three years ago I was still using them :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=welcomeLink.action">
```

This is also a working one,

```
<%  
response.sendRedirect("welcomeLink.action");
%>
```

But in my experience it will work only when it is in index page, or any other page which is loaded as first page.

If I put response.sendRedirect in any successor page it will not work [Reffer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9866964/1041341)

Comment: In index.jsp you need to add only this line. It will goes to your Struts.xml and find mappings for this action.
It will work