# redirect to an action then to another jsp using <s:action> in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

My index.jsp is

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
 <head>
<title>HOME</title>
</head>

<body>
Hi you are in index.jsp page
<s:action name="error" executeResult="true"></s:action>
</body>
</html>
```

my error action class is

```
public class error extends ActionSupport {
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("in error action.........");
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

my struts.xml

```
<action name="error" class="action.error">            
        <result name="success" type="redirect">                                                      
            <param name="location">/Login.jsp</param>
        </result>            
</action>
```

i want to redirect to Login.jsp when i hit the index.jsp page. but every time i hit index.jsp i come back to my index.jsp page but this time it is blank. it is going to action as it is printing "in error action.........". But it is not redirecting to Login.jsp

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> what am i doing wrong?

Basically everything.

1. Class names must start with a capitalized letter, according to [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#15411):

   ```java
   public class Error extends ActionSupport {
   ```
2. Naming `error` an action returning login data (or page) is a big violation of the [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment); a name like `login` fits a lot better;
3. [`redirect`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/redirect-result.html) result must point to an URL, generally external (eg. `http://www.google.com/`). To redirect to an action, use [`redirectAction`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/redirect-action-result.html) result, to point to a view (eg. a JSP) use the default result, [`dispatcher`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/dispatcher-result.html) (that can be omitted).

   ```xml
   <action name="login" class="action.Login">  
       <result name="success">/Login.jsp</result>
   </action>
   ```
4. Using `<s:action>` tag is 99% of times unnecessary, and sometimes also wrong, like in this case, because the result execution will be injected in the main page. You could inject a JSP snippet containing a Javascript block with a `window.location.href = something`, but this is not the Circus; 
   redirect **the right way**, by either using the [meta refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3186669/1654265), or (much better) by not even landing on the `index.jsp`, redirecting directly from the `Index.action` (with a `redirectAction` result) to the `Login.action`, and then landing on `login.jsp`.

   Otherwise, you could use a small Scriptlet like this:

   ```xml
   <% response.sendRedirect("/login.action"); %>
   ```

   but not from included JSPs, only from top level.